# how to work around "Your device does not qualify for bootloader unlocking

Tags: recovery-mode, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I've followed the [guides](https://digitz.org/blog/unlock-bootloader-moto-ubuntu-mint/) but stupid Motorola is telling me that I can't unlock the bootloader so I'm blocked with

```
sudo ./fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.2-0-surnia.img 
(bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
sending 'recovery' (16152 KB)...
OKAY [  0.509s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.921s
```

I'm working from an Ubuntu box.

Comment: This is a known problem, mostly encountered with Chrome browser. Try Mozilla Browser to get the validation code. Unless i Misunderstood your problem

Comment: Same error in Firefox

Comment: Then it may be a different issue, you will need to search in Moto forums. You can perhaps try some other browser?

Comment: I checked https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87215, it appears that MOTO E (1st & 2nd Generation) is supported but not with 4G LTE which is what I have. I guess Motorola screwed up for its customers.

Comment: Sad. Please mention device on your question. If Motorola didn't give you the code, then it is a dead end

Comment: You can try trucks here but unlikely to work i guess http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2658218&page=3

Comment: i don't understand! are you flashing the recovery before unlocking bootloader? because usually we unlock bootloader first with {fastboot oem unlock} command. is your bootloader unlocked already? if not then do so(on your own risk) . also you can try installing fastboot from Google repo instead of using it as binary from Android studio tools. benefit is it'll give you updated and bugfree version. also search for "preflash validation failed" error on moto E or any moto forums(xda) i got plenty of results that are similar to your problem

Comment: Spark, no, I just say that I can't flash because the bootloader is locked. @beeshyams moto xt1527 is the device in question and _none_ of the solutions from XDA work for me, not even the SunShine unlocker.

Comment: Well, I was expecting it not to work as mentioned earlier, since OEM is yet to permit unlocking boot loader. Sorry for that, but best would be to chase OEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the "cid" of the device by doing

```
./adb reboot bootloader
sudo ./fastboot getvar all
```

In my case it gives

```
(bootloader) cid: 0x0001
```

and as you can see at [the official website](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTOROLA-Android-Developer/Bootloader-Unlock-Problems/m-p/3222809), Lenovo/Motorola says "Your device is NOT eligible for bootloader unlock". You *buy* their phone and they still control it. Wait, what?

Comment: what do you use the cid for? I understand that that is what is says on the site, but why do I need to look up the cid?